# Unable to mount hard drive after upgrading

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, installation

after upgrading to 11.04 system starts to boot and then can not find hard drive. It gives me the option to skip or manual. I am a newb and don't know how to do it manually and then set it to auto mount. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the contents of `/etc/fstab` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a invalid entry in your /etc/fstab it may be asking you to skip the mounting of the filesystem, or to try to mount it manually.

If this is indeed the case, you may want to edit the /etc/fstab file and either comment out, delete, or correct the line for the filesystem in question.

I normally see these kind of messages when i add a external usb hard drive to my /etc/fstab then remove the drive and forget to edit the fstab back to normal.

If this is not the case, you may want to give the full error message. and perhaps  any information from your /etc/fstab on the filesystem in question.